# What is the best way to calculate a checksum for a file that is on my machine?

Tags: windows, checksum

I'm on a Windows machine and I want to run a checksum on the MySQL distribution I just got.  It looks like there are products to download, an unsupported Microsoft tool, and probably other options.  I'm wondering if there is a consensus for the best tool to use.  This may be a really easy question, I've just never run a checksum routine before.

Comment: Also discussed on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any MD5 will produce a good checksum to verify the file.  Any of the files listed at the bottom of this page will work fine.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum

Comment: This answer is no longer good advice. MD5 is [vastly insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) nowadays. Using MD5 to validate downloaded files is not secure.

Comment: @antiduh Seeing as you get the hash from the same place you download it from, your argument is moot. You're limited by the hash provided by the website.

Comment: Let's note that the user just wants to verify that the downloaded file has not been corrupted. If you take a look at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) you will come across this key sentence in the opening paragraph: _"Although MD5 was initially designed to be used as a cryptographic hash function, it has been found to suffer from extensive vulnerabilities. It can still be used as a checksum to verify data integrity, but only against unintentional corruption."_

Comment: @J.J A lot of official websites make you download the actual binary from another domain, so the argument is valid. You can download a modified VLC from a malicious mirror via the official site, which will be detected by a checksum.

Comment: @antiduh then why don't you suggest the alternative?

Comment: @Arno - That is my exact point. A malicious mirror could assemble a VLC binary that has a virus in it, but has the same exact checksum as published on the website; that is because Hash-MD5 is insecure. HMAC-MD5 is better (for now), but there are still better alternatives.

Comment: @java-addict301 - Because I'm not here to hold your hand. You could spend about 5 minutes searching for hashing best practices and find an up-to-date answer. Owasp.org is a great resource.

Comment: @antiduh I asked not because I'm too lazy to search, but because RTFM is never an appropriate 'answer' on Stackoverflow (which is what your answer implied).

Answer (score 269):

The [**CertUtil**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) is a pre-installed Windows utility, that can be used to generate hash checksums:

```
CertUtil -hashfile pathToFileToCheck [HashAlgorithm]
```

*`HashAlgorithm`* choices: MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512

So for example, the following generates an MD5 checksum for the file `C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img`:

```
CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5
```

To get output similar to *Nix systems you can add some PS magic:

```
$(CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5)[1] -replace " ",""
```

Comment: This is a much easier choice than FCIV, given that this is pre-installed .

Comment: Note: this doesn't come pre-installed on Win XP, but given that that OS is now obsolete, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: for XP/2003 Admin tool kit  are needed - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7045

Comment: @Laisvis - with your explanation, I went from 0 to done in about 2 minutes. I came to this page looking for how to do it. Your answer was simple and perfect.

Comment: +1 for recommending pre-installed version.  What better way to ensure secure software to check security and save additional steps hunting, downloading, installing, and validating.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to check file checksum for using certUtil generated Hash ? command line. Would that be just use the same commandline to generate the Hash on the file (after the file was received on the target machine) ?

Comment: How would you go about using that to make a simple hash out of a string rather than a file?

Comment: Where can I find the list of available hash-algorithms? I tried `certutil -hashfile -?` but did not get the list of options. The [website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_hashfile) does not have it as well.

Comment: @RavindraHV CertUtil has changed/evolved subtly over time.  I just checked: in 2008 (~Windows 7) it doesn't list them, but in 2012R2 (~Windows 8.1) or later it does.  I'd just try each in the above list, just note the older versions are probably case-sensitive ('MD5' not 'md5').

Comment: I agree with this approach, and it is the one I would use for taking a fingerprint of a file to check its integrity. I just want to add that these days MD5 IS NOT GOOD FOR ANY OTHER CRYPTOGRAPHIC USE CASE other than this.  :-) Happy Hashing

Answer (score 29):

I personally use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which puts the entire smörgåsbord of Linux utilities at my fingertip --- there's [`md5sum`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum) and all the cryptographic digests supported by [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/). Alternatively, you can also use a [Windows distribution](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) of OpenSSL (the "light" version is only a 1 MB installer).

Comment: For just checking a checksum Cygwin seems a little heavy.  Especially since there are 5KB executable for checking the MD5

Comment: It might be heavy but it is a valid answer, particularly when considering a Unixy program (MySQL) is involved.

Comment: For those of us who consider Cygwin an essential tool, it's a perfect answer.

Comment: It is worth noting that md5sum also comes with git bash (mingw)

Answer (score 9):

On Windows : you can use FCIV utility : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290

On Unix/Linux : you can use md5sum : http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_md5sum.htm

Comment: FCIV isn't pre-installed. CertUtil is (on newer Windows OSes) - See answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28922976/3063884

Comment: Hence the download location is provided.

Comment: broken, links. Maybe stackoverflow should run bots that check all the threads for broken links, I mean this is the future.

Answer (score 6):

Checksum tabs: http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/

This has worked great for me on windows for a while now. It allows easy copying and pasting of checksums. It has box to type/paste check sums from webpages and show matches or non matches quite well.

Comment: This handy little utility is rather understated here. First I have no relation to the author(s)---I just think it is a great utility! It lets you generate a hash file of your choice from the context menu in Windows Explorer for a single file or a group of files. You can later double-click that hash file to automatically run a hash verification of those files. I use this frequently to generate a hash for large files I want to copy, then copy the hash file with it, and at the destination, double-click to verify they survived intact.

Comment: Excellent solution, but the link is outdated. The safest place to get this software now is https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck

Answer (score 5):

On MySQL.com, MD5s are listed alongside each file that you can download.  For instance, MySQL "Windows Essentials" 5.1 is **528c89c37b3a6f0bd34480000a56c372**.

You can [download](http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/) md5 (md5.exe), a command line tool that will calculate the MD5 of any file that you have locally.  MD5 is just like any other [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), which means that a given array of bytes will always produce the same hash.  That means if your downloaded MySQL zip file (or whatever) has the same MD5 as they post on their site, you have the exact same file.

Answer (score 3):

When I worked with Windows, I found handy HashTab 3rd party tool. It shows MD5, SHA-1 check sums in one of file properties tabs. http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/

Answer (score 3):

7-Zip can be used to generate hashes for files, folders of files, and trees of folders of files.  7-Zip is small footprint and a very useful compression utility.  http://7-zip.org/

Comment: While it is true that 7-zip provides hashes for all of the items listed above, it lacks a way to simply copy-paste it's results directly. CertUtil, since it is a CMD program, does provide copy-paste functionality.

Comment: It's also possible to use 7z.exe via the CMD, for example `7z.exe h -scrcSHA256 -- /path/to/your/file.txt` produces a sha256 hash.

Answer (score 3):

To calculate md5 of all the files in the current directory in windows 7

```
for %i in (*) DO CertUtil -hashfile %i MD5
```

Answer (score 2):

Download fciv.exe directly from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11533

```
shell> fciv.exe [yourfile]
```

will give you md5 by default.

You can read up the help file `fciv.exe -h`

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another option for Windows users, the `Get-FileHash` PowerShell cmdlet can be used (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx).

Example usage:
`Get-FileHash MyImage.iso -Algorithm MD5`

If all you're after is just the raw hash then:
`(Get-FileHash MyImage.iso -Algorithm MD5).Hash`

Answer (score 1):

The Powershell utility Get-FileHash worked perfectly for me.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash

Answer (score 1):

Best utility for Windows is HashCheck that is now on GitHub.
https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck/releases/tag/v2.4.0

Install HashCheck.
Now right click on the file -> Create verification file.
It will create a file.extension.md5 file with MD5 code in it.

Love it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the above solutions will not tell you if your installation is correct only if your install.exe is correct (you can trust it to produce a correct install.)

You would need MD5 sums for each file/folder to test if the installed code has been messed with after the install completed.

WinMerg is useful to compare two installs (on two different machines perhaps) to see if one has been changed or why one is broken.

Answer (score 0):

for sure the certutil is the best approach but there's a chance to hit windows xp/2003 machine without certutil command.There makecab command can be used which has its own hash algorithm - here the [fileinf.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/makecab/fileinf.bat) which will output some info about the file including the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

[Hashing](http://hashingapp.github.io) is a standalone application that performs MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-2 family. Built upon OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [HashMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html) for windows.

Answer (score 0):

QuickHash an open source tool supporting **MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA512** and available for the **Linux, Windows, and Apple Mac**.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickhash/

Answer (score 0):

In  HPUX ( hp UNIX)

Please install the md5sum package on your UNIX machine for example, if there is a file called a.txt

```
shell > md5sum a.txt
```

Answer (score -4):

Just use win32 Checksum api. MD5 is native in Win32.

Comment: Have an example of the Win32 API that is small enough for an SO answer and suitable for the asker?