# Determine the SQL Server JDBC version on command line

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have several servers which use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver. The files are all named `sqljdbc4.jar`.  I need to know what version of the driver each one contains. Time stamps and file sizes are not helpful, as I need to extract the driver version number. I need to be able to run this on the command line.

I have seen for DB2 you can run this command and get the version:

```
java -cp ./db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
```

What is the equivalent, if any, for Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834794/how-to-check-the-version-of-jar-file , might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that there is no dedicated CLI to print out the driver version but you can ask the MS 4.x driver for its version:

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
...
Driver driver = new SQLServerDriver();
driver.getMajorVersion();  // -> 4
driver.getMinorVersion();  // -> 0, 1, 2, ...
```

You could build a simple commandline wrapper to print out this information.

Answer (score 1):

IBM provides specific tooling in its JAR to provide for the behavior you describe.  It is not a general feature of JDBC drivers or of JAR files.

Microsoft documents the available mechanisms for determining the driver version [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378476%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).  They offer two alternatives:

- extract the information from an [`SQLServer`]`DatabaseMetaData` object obtained via the driver (i.e. by a Java program); the most appropriate method for your use appears to be `getDriverVersion()`.  Or
- extract the information from the `readme.txt` file provided in the distribution.

Unless `readme.txt` is packaged in the JAR (possible, but unlikely), the former approach is the only one that will work with the JAR file alone.  It shouldn't be too hard to write a Java program and maybe a wrapper script to apply this approach to the task, but it doesn't look anywhere near as simple as for the DB2 driver.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Java decompiler, you can open the SQLJDBC JAR with the decompiler and check this decompiled class: com\microsoft\sqlserver\jdbc\SQLJdbcVersion.class
It shows version info like the following:

```
final class SQLJdbcVersion
{
   static final int major = 4;
   static final int minor = 0;
   static final int MMDD = 2206;
   static final int revision = 100;
}
```

I do not know if that class is available in all versions of the SQLJDBC JAR, but I have found it in the 3.0, 4.0, and 4.2 JARs. GitHub (link below) also shows it present in versions 6 thru 8.  All versions appear to include the "major" and "minor" variables; the other variables which are included differ depending on the version.

To fetch that data from the command line, perhaps you could create a script to invoke the decompiler, then extract the major and minor values from the decompiled file, and delete the decompiled file(s).

The SQL Server JDBC driver is open-source, according to this page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/frequently-asked-questions-faq-for-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15

> The JDBC Driver is open-source and the source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc).

Therefore, there should be no legality issues in decompiling the JARs.

The current GitHub "dev" branch version of the code shows these values:

```
final class SQLJdbcVersion {
   static final int major = 8;
   static final int minor = 4;
   static final int patch = 0;
   static final int build = 0;
   /*
    * Used to load mssql-jdbc_auth DLL.
    * 1. Set to "-preview" for preview release.
    * 2. Set to "" (empty String) for official release.
    */
   static final String releaseExt = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this one liner for getting the internal MSSQL driver version:

```
$ echo "System.out.println(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData(null).getDriverVersion())" | /usr/java/jdk-11.0.2/bin/jshell -q --class-path mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre10.jar

jshell> System.out.println(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData(null).getDriverVersion())
7.0.0.0
```

*jshell* command is available starting from JDK9. Alternatively you can also use *jrunscript* on JDK8

```
$ jrunscript -cp mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre10.jar -e "java.lang.System.out.println(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData(null).getDriverVersion())"

Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
7.0.0.0
```