# How to check version of android-support-v13.jar

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an android project developed on eclipse. I migrated it to Android Studio and updated the support libraries. It started showing some weired behavior related to UI. The project had some nested scrolling functionality which was not supported then. Now the support library itself provides support for nested scrolling so that is causing problem. Is there any way through which we can know what was version of support library.jar? Since in eclipse we used to add jar files in the libs folder.

Comment: Do you need to keep the jar? Why can't you switch to the Gradle dependency?

Comment: Rename your .jar to .zip and unzip it. Check the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834794/how-to-check-the-version-of-jar-file

Comment: @cricket_007 I had already switched to gradle dependency. But due to problem nested scroll the new support library is causing UI issues in my app, as I mentioned in my post. And its not possible for me to rectify all those in one go. That's why I was curious to know.