# Check Java 3rd party library version from command line

Tags: java, command-line

I could not find an answer to this question, as it differs slightly from other similar questions on here. I have a 3rd party library that is a custom library that is not yet in Maven. It is a jar file. I want to know if there is a standard way to check the version of it from the command line? I have seen other users write up code to check, but I don't want that, just a quick command from the command line (if one exists).

So I am thinking, maybe there is a standard format that the jar files uses to store the version? I don't know if this is true, but curious if there is a way to get the version. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like checking the Manifest file? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check the version of jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834794/how-to-check-the-version-of-jar-file)

Comment: Maybe, I will check this. Thanks!

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!