# ANT to Gradle Migration - dependency issues

Tags: java, gradle, websphere

In the process of migrating my java applications from ANT to Gradle tool
My ear application includes jar and war such as like EJB module, web module and util module.
I have completed rewriting from build.xml into `build.gradle` and build successful. ear generated as well.
But when I am trying to deploy in WebSphere I am able to deploy the application.
The issue is when I start the application in WebSphere am not able to start the application. I am getting below error.

```
[‎1/‎6/‎2020 6:22 AM]  
[1/6/20 6:20:17:720 EST] 0000009c annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.manulife.pension.heartbeat.servlet.HeartBeatServlet
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:403)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnn
```

I have declared this package `com.manulife.pension.heartbeat.servlet.HeartBeatServlet` as `heartbeat.jar` in dependencies in ejb module's build.gradle and ear module build.gradle as well:

```
implementation(group: 'heartbeat', name: 'heartbeat', version: '1.0')
```

My `heartbeat.jar` is added as heartbeat-1.0.jar in Gradle as we know in Maven and Gradle these dependencies are added with versions in names.

When I replace this `heartbeat-1.0.jar` with `heartbeat.jar` in deployed ear above error is vanished

Can someone please help me how we can handle these naming issues for dependencies ? should we declare somewhere because the issue is coming at runtime!!

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834843/2158271) how you can try to determine the right version of JAR.

If you can't determine the right version add JAR to you Gradle project as a [local file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956456/2158271).