# How to know what JDK version a project is developed on?

Tags: java, github, java-8, version, javadoc

I need to use a Java library (https://github.com/esig/dss) in C# using IKVM.NET.
IKVM.NET supports JDK 8, how can I know if the library is using a later version?
It doesn't really appear anywhere on the documentation or on the JavaDoc. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [You can look at the manifest of the library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5834794/5515060)

Comment: The library has a pom.xml file which shows the current version available in the `master` branch

https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: as @ItAssistors said,  lib has pom.xml. Maven compiler plugin talks about supported java version (https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/pom.xml#L193). What is not clear here is , release tag under configuration says 8. However, release configuration works only after java version 9. There are other dependencies which needs java 9(https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/pom.xml#L344). So I think lib requires Java 9 atleast

Comment: Thank you Lino, It Assistors and Pramod!

Comment: @Lino Looking at the manifest is not sufficient: you can use Java 14 to target Java 8 for compilation.

Comment: @Pramod That could just indicate that they are using Java 11 or higher to compile, while targeting Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling the Java project, to make sure which java version was used you can execute this command on one of the class file generated (javap is a binary located in your JAVA_HOME directory) :

```
javap -verbose <Name of your class>.class | grep "major version"
```

Example of output :

```
major version: 52
```

And the following list will give you the mapping between the major version and the java version :

- Java 5 uses major version 49
- Java 6 uses major version 50
- Java 7 uses major version 51
- Java 8 uses major version 52
- Java 9 uses major version 53
- Java 10 uses major version 54
- Java 11 uses major version 55
- etc...