# Automate obtaining the SHA256 for a file to download with Inno Setup 6.1?

Tags: inno-setup, checksum, inno-setup-v6

The documentation for [`DownloadTemporaryFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478722/850848#28922976) says this about the `RequiredSHA256OfFile` parameter:

> If `RequiredSHA256OfFile` is set it will compare this to the SHA-256 of the downloaded file and raise an exception if the hashes don't match.
>
> An exception will be raised if there was an error. Otherwise, returns the number of bytes downloaded. Returns 0 if `RequiredSHA256OfFile` is set and the file was already downloaded.

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478722/850848#28922976) I have determined that the correct commandline method to obtain the checksum is:

```
CertUtil -hashfile MSAHelpDocumentationSetup.exe SHA256
```

This is how I add adding this particular file to my script:

```pascal
AddFileForDownload('{#HelpDocSetupURL}', 'HelpDocSetup.exe');
```

Which expands to:

```pascal
procedure AddFileForDownload(Url, FileName: string);
begin
    DownloadPage.Add(Url, FileName, '');
    FilesToDownload := FilesToDownload + '      ' + ExtractFileName(FileName) + #13#10;
    Log('File to download: ' + Url);
end;
```

Is there way to automate:

1. Obtaining the checksum for my file.
2. Caching that checksum into a string.
3. Using that checksum value when building the script.

By automating this task it will provide two benefits:

- Minimize user error in copy /pasting the checksum value.
- Keep the checksum update to date without user interaction.

Is this feasible in Inno Setup with Pascal Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal Script won't help you. You need the value at the compile time. So using a preprocessor. You can indeed execute the `certutil`. But imo, in this case, it's easier to use PowerShell and its [`Get-FileHash` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash):

```
#define GetSHA256OfFile(FileName) \
  Local[0] = AddBackslash(GetEnv("TEMP")) + "sha256.txt", \
  Local[1] = \
    "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command """ + \
    "Set-Content -Path '" + Local[0] + "' -NoNewline -Value " + \
    "(Get-FileHash('" + FileName + "')).Hash" + \
    """", \
  Exec("powershell.exe", Local[1], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(Local[0]), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  DeleteFileNow(Local[0]), \
  LowerCase(Local[3])
```

And then you can use it like:

```pascal
AddFileForDownload(
  '{#HelpDocSetupURL}', 'HelpDocSetup.exe', '{#GetSHA256OfFile("HelpDocSetup.exe")}');
```

You of course need to add the third parameter to your `AddFileForDownload` function and pass it to `TDownloadWizardPage.Add`. You also may need to add a path to the file, so that the preprocessor can find it.